# data table is not updating after saving the record

Tags: lightning-web-components

I created data table with edit button. When I click on edit button it will open the lightning record edit from in Lightning Modal window. When Click on Save button in Modal window it is not reflecting in data table?

```
<template>
    
    <div class="slds-m-top_medium slds-m-bottom_x-large">
        <h2 class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-m-bottom_medium" >
            Button-icons with the <code>variant</code> attribute omitted or set to the default value of <code>border</code>.
        </h2>
        <!-- with border / by default -->
        <div class="slds-p-around_medium lgc-bg">
            <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:add"  alternative-text="New Request" title="New request" onclick={showModalpopUp}></lightning-button-icon>
            <template if:true={isModalpopupTrue}>
                <!-- //<c-modal-popup-component></c-modal-popup-component> -->
                <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
                    <div class="slds-modal__container">
                     <!-- modal header start -->
                       <header class="slds-modal__header">
                          <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse" title="Close" onclick={hideModalBox}>
                             <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:close"
                                alternative-text="close"
                                variant="inverse"
                                size="small" ></lightning-icon>
                             <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
                          </button>
                          <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">Leave Request</h2>
                       </header>
                   
                       <!-- modal body start -->
                       <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
                        <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name={objectApiName}
                        record-id={recordId} onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
                        <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
                        <lightning-input-field   field-name={user}> </lightning-input-field>
                        <lightning-input-field   field-name={FromDate}> </lightning-input-field>
                        <lightning-input-field   field-name={Todate}> </lightning-input-field>
                        <lightning-input-field   field-name={Reason}> </lightning-input-field>
                        <lightning-button  variant="brand"  type="submit" name="save" label="Save">
                        </lightning-button> 
                        <lightning-button   name="Cancel" label="Cancel" onclick={HandleResetButton}>
                        </lightning-button>
                        </lightning-record-edit-form>
                             
                       </div>
             
                       <!-- modal footer start
                       <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                        <lightning-button  variant="brand"  type="submit" name="save" label="Save">
                        </lightning-button>
                          <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" onclick={hideModalBox}>Cancel</button>
                       </footer> -->
                    
                    </div>
                 </section>
                 <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
            
            </template>
        </div>
        <div style="height: 300px;">
            <lightning-datatable
                    key-field="id"
                    data={tabledata}
                    columns={columns}
                    hide-checkbox-column
                    onrowaction={handleRowAction}>
            </lightning-datatable>
        </div>
    </div>        
</template>
```

JS FILE>>>>

```
@wire(getLeaveRequest) leaverequest(result){

            this.leavedata = result;
            if(result.data){
            this.tabledata = result.data;
            //refreshApex(this.tabledata);
            console.log('Get the table data is >>>>>'+this.tabledata)
            }
           if(result.error){
            console.log('Get the table data error is >>>>>')
            }
    }

    handleSuccess(event){
        this.recordId = event.detail.id;
        console.log('get the recordid is'+this.recordId);
         refreshApex(this.tabledata); 
        console.log(' Get the details are '+JSON.stringify(this.tabledata)) 
         this.dispatchEvent(new RefreshEvent()); 
        console.log('Refresh >>>  $$$$$$$$$')
        this.isModalpopupTrue = false;
        refreshApex(this.tabledata);
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
refreshApex(this.tabledata)
```

Should be:

```
refreshApex(this.leavedata)
```

The main result parameter contains a third "hidden" property that `refreshApex` uses to know which wire handler to call.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox.  can  we also refresh the table by using the RefreshView API ? I tried by using this.dispatchEvent(new RefreshEvent());
But the data table is not refreshing after saving record